# Do we have to return full buffers each time our AVIO `read_packet()` callback from FFMPEG is called?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, callback

I allocate an AVIO context with my own `read_packet()` implementation. Only my implementation is such that I may return with a `count` smaller than the required input `buf_size`. Is that allowed? Or do we have to fill the buffer as much as possible each time out `read_packet()` function gets called?

```
// initialization
    [...snip...]
    m_avio_context.reset(avio_alloc_context(
                          avio_buffer
                        , avio_buffer_size
                        , 0             // write flag
                        , this          // opaque
                        , &FFMPEGDecoder::decoder_read_static
                        , nullptr       // write func.
                        , nullptr));    // seek func.
    [...snip...]

// implementation of static function
int FFMPEGDecoder::decoder_read_static(void * opaque, std::uint8_t * buf, int size)
{
    return reinterpret_cast<FFMPEGDecoder *>(opaque)->decoder_read(buf, size);
}

// the actual read_packet()
int FFMPEGDecoder::decoder_read(std::uint8_t * buf, int size)
{
    // in flushing mode, we won't receive any more packets
    //
    if(m_flushing)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    // m_packet is my own packet implementation (an std::vector<>)
    //
    while(m_packet == nullptr
       || static_cast<std::size_t>(m_read_pos) >= m_packet->size())
    {
        if(!m_incoming_packets.pop_front(m_packet, -1))
        {
            return 0;
        }
        if(m_packet->is_flush())
        {
            m_flushing = true;
            return 0;
        }
        m_read_pos = 0;
    }

    // the number of bytes to copy size `size` or less if there are
    // less bytes available in my m_packet
    //
    int const copy(std::min(static_cast<std::size_t>(size), m_packet->size() - m_read_pos));

    memcpy(buf, m_packet->data().data() + m_read_pos, copy);

    m_read_pos += copy;

    return copy;
}
```

I'm not looking for a way to fill the buffer, I'm going to implement it that way now. I'm looking for confirmation (or not) that the FFMPEG libraries are not capable of accepting less than `size` bytes in `buf` when our `read_packet()` gets called.

Do you know?

Comment: I speculate here, but in video decoding, especially in (live) streams, you may not know in advance what is coming from the stream next, it may depend on the content of the current decoded packets (e.g. there could be optional headers and metadata etc. in the transport stream). I don't know, but logical to me is "size" to be a maxmum or so, because the actual amount depends on the decoding and concrete structure of the data that's discovered in the raw input.  A hint to me is also this line: https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.1/avio__reading_8c_source.html 45:buf_size = FFMIN(buf_size, bd->size)

Comment: That code, though, ends once `buf_size = 0`, meaning "end of file" (i.e. they run through one buffer; in my case, I run through many buffers). But it looks like my issue was in a different place where I used the wrong size field (so many sizes!)

Comment: Something else that seems related from PyAV's docs (it's a wrapper, but a low level one):  https://pyav.org/docs/develop/api/codec.html#av.codec.Codec.capabilities
see "delay" field: "Encoder or decoder requires flushing with NULL input at the end in order to give the complete and correct output. (...) Decoders: The decoder has a non-zero delay and needs to be fed with avpkt->data=NULL, avpkt->size=0 at the end to get the delayed data until the decoder no longer returns frames(...)The encoder needs to be fed with NULL data at the end of encoding until the encoder no longer returns data.

Comment: Also this parsing example: https://pyav.org/docs/develop/cookbook/basics.html#parsing

codec = av.CodecContext.create('h264', 'r')
while True:
    chunk = fh.read(1 << 16)
    packets = codec.parse(chunk)
    print("Parsed {} packets from {} bytes:".format(len(packets), len(chunk)))
    for packet in packets:
      (...)

The file is read in chunks of 64KB, packets are parsed etc., the final one could be < 64KB. I guess the codec context keeps track of the overlaps between sebsequent chunks and preserves it in another buffer. It has to remember current keyframes etc. anyway.

Comment: @Twenkid Yeah, the state machine is complicated... My problem was not at the end, it would happen along the way, some gaps appear with the audio going to 0s. I could test again and see whether it works now without my extra loop... it feels like it will work, but I'm thinking that it may also depend on the decoder in use. With a WAV file, it may work just fine, with an AAC or OGG it may fail... who knows. It's not well documented.

Comment: I also think WAV might be more robust, because samples can be cut exactly at 1/frequency timing, while the compressed formats with their "frames" may have little skews/desyncs in regard to the video frame lenght and may need to be padded with 0s etc. Along the way -  I'd dump the sound track and check the pattern of the gaps and how they are located compared to the timing of the frames (e.g. 25 fps, frame start: 0.0, 0.04, 0.08, ...); and eventually how that changes in regard to changing the buffer/chunk size etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is pretty old but just in case someone is having (like I had) the same question:

**It's not a problem to give less bytes than required as argument.**

From personal experience I have no decoding issue by providing a small amount of bytes as soon as available, even if the byte count is much lower than required (the library is anyway going to call the read function again later if needed).

**However**, the returned value should be above 0, unless the stream you are reading is over (in which case you are expected to return `AVERROR_EOF` instead of 0).

It means that if you are working on a network stream for example, and if your read function gets called while you are running out of pending bytes to provide, you may need to implement a wait mechanism inside your read function, to avoid returning `AVERROR_EOF` before being sure that the stream is actually over.
After having returned `AVERROR_EOF`, it would still be possible to go back to decoding functions once more bytes of the same stream are available again, but from personal experience, you're going to have decoding glitches when doing so.

Hope this may help someone!